# How to write Auto documentation for gulp tasks?

Tags: javascript, documentation, gulp, jsdoc

How can I use JSDoc to auto-generate documentation for files making up gulp tasks?

For example, I have a task file called `assets`. I would like to write some simple descriptions in the file itself and have JSDoc generate the actual documentation automatically with gulp.

```
var gulp          = require('gulp');
var documentation = require("jsdocs");

/**
 * A simple task to generate documentation for individual tasks.
 * @constructor
 */

gulp.task('docs',  function() {

  return gulp.src("./gulp/tasks/assets.js")
    .pipe(documentation())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./md-documentation'));
});
```

I'd like to automatically write documentation by simply describing the task above it.

How do I do this with JSDoc?

Answer (score 2):

I got this working using jsdocs.

This assumes you have a folder structure that I do:

```
gulp/
    tasks/
    utils/
    index.js
    README.md
    config.js
src/
gulpfile.js
package.json
bower.json
```

The gulp tasks folder, contains any gulp:

Build a gulp task called **docs**.

under `gulp/tasks/_documentation.js`

I have:

```
'use strict';

var gulp          = require('gulp'),
    runSequence   = require('run-sequence'),
    browserSync   = require('browser-sync'),
    jsdoc         = require('gulp-jsdoc');



/** @module Docs */

function Docs() {


    /**
     * A simple task to generate documentation for the gulp application. tasks.
     * @example gulp docs
     * @memberof module:Docs
     */

    var docs = {

        options: {
            srcFiles: ["./gulp/README.md", "./gulp/config.js", "./gulp/tasks/*.js"],
            destination: './doc/jsdoc/'
        },

        /**
         * A simple task to generate documentation for the gulp application. tasks.
         * @name docs
         * @example gulp docs
         * @memberoof module:Docs
         */     
        bundle: function() {
            gulp.task('docs',  function(cb) {
              return runSequence(
                'docs:build',
                'docs:serve',
                cb
              );
            });
        },
        build: function() {
            var options = this.options;

            var destination = options.destination;          


            var template = {                
                path : 'ink-docstrap',
                theme : 'flatly'
            };

            gulp.task('docs:build',  function() {
              gulp.src(options.srcFiles)
                .pipe(jsdoc.parser())
                .pipe(jsdoc.generator(destination, template))
            });
        },
        serve: function() {
            var options = this.options;
            gulp.task('docs:serve', function() {
              return browserSync.init({
                open: true,
                server: {
                  baseDir: options.destination,
                  // index : 'module-Config.html'
                },
                ghostMode: {
                  links: false
                }
              });

            });
        }
    };
    return docs;
}


module.exports = Docs();
```

Using jsDocs documentation, you can document your code the same as I have in this _documentation.js module.

Once you run `gulp docs` it will spawn up a new browser instance, giving you a clean website with easy to follow Modularised -> tasks with all your documentation inside the code itself.